# TypeScript Does not Properly Infer the Type of an Object's Property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create an object where each property is mapped to a class instance. The class type relies on two generics. When I access a property in my object, TypeScript infers the type of the property as the union type used to define the object rather than the type of the property itself.

How can I get TypeScript to infer the type of the property properly?

Here is a code snippet to help clarify the problem:

```js
export class CacheWithExpiry<T extends CacheTypes, V extends CacheNames> {
    constructor() {
    }
    ...
}

export type CacheNames =
  'foo_1' |
  'foo_2'

type CacheTypes = string | number

type CacheMap<T extends CacheTypes, V extends CacheNames> = { [key: string]: CacheWithExpiry<T, V> }

export const cacheMap: CacheMap<CacheTypes, CacheNames> = {
  foo1Cache: new CacheWithExpiry<string, 'foo_1'>(), // Type is inferred as expected 'CacheWithExpiry<string, "foo_1">'
  foo2Cache: new CacheWithExpiry<number, 'foo_2'>()
} as const

cacheMap.foo1Cache// Type is inferred as 'CacheWithExpiry<CacheTypes, CacheNames>' instead of 'CacheWithExpiry<string, "foo_1">'
```

Edit 1: I also need to maintain type safety for `cacheMap` so removing the type completely from `cacheMap` wouldn't work. Example:

```js
export const cacheMap = {
  foo1Cache: new CacheWithExpiry<string, 'foo_1'>(),
  foo2Cache: new CacheWithExpiry<number, 'foo_2'>(),
  foo3: 'I am not a cache class instance', // I still want this to throw an error
} as const
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned the type `CacheMap<CacheTypes, CacheNames>` to the variable `cacheMap`. This type does not hold any information about the keys `foo1Cache` or `foo12ache`. All it knows is that there could be any key of type `string` which would hold a value of type `CacheWithExpiry<CacheTypes, CacheNames>`. That is why when you access a property of `cacheMap`, TypeScript will not know about the specific properties.

If you take away the type though, TypeScript will know the properties and their types:

```
export const cacheMap = {
  foo1Cache: new CacheWithExpiry<string, 'foo_1'>(),
  foo2Cache: new CacheWithExpiry<number, 'foo_2'>()
} as const

cacheMap.foo1Cache // foo1Cache: CacheWithExpiry<string, "foo_1">
```

The type of `cacheMap` is now:

```
const cacheMap: {
    readonly foo1Cache: CacheWithExpiry<string, "foo_1">;
    readonly foo2Cache: CacheWithExpiry<number, "foo_2">;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GEUIBbADqAljHgKLjFQCeAPACpygzAB2AJpjvsAzWGBoANHABqzEK07dcBAHIoAtkIB8cAN4BYAFBx9iCGzQwoAVwQxoACgCUm3QbgBfXa527QkWHBgDg2HLAiiqYALyOcADkAGYQEAD6AIxRcAA%20kbHxCQBMUbq6foKBvPyC4XAmUMRsAObpcGxmSgBGwFAFOkUBPAQAsihgjJLSXCUEZUKiEizsY73BympwYZpwANoA0nA143z%20aAC6AFx7JGSUYNT0DNPq7p7g0PAIRiaIQQNgKw56cHEQJILU5sYAAdzOpAoVFodCqNVqoiyiRSqjswkiAJywMa4MhFxh9CarXaSIBuSiaNsbjg6EMxhgnQQn0GADoAUCgnAAPTc-7xTm8U4Lc7Qq6w%20F1UQAInJSWlqiAA)

---

If you also want type validation when creating the `cacheMap` object, you need to pass the object literal to a generic function.

```
function createCacheMap<T extends CacheMap<CacheTypes, CacheNames>>(cacheMap: T): T {
  return cacheMap
}

export const cacheMap = createCacheMap({
  foo1Cache: new CacheWithExpiry<string, 'foo_1'>(),
  foo2Cache: new CacheWithExpiry<number, 'foo_2'>(),
  anything: "string" // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CacheWithExpiry<CacheTypes, CacheNames>
})

cacheMap.foo1Cache // foo1Cache: CacheWithExpiry<string, "foo_1">
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=22&pln=25&pc=112#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GEUIBbADqAljHgKLjFQCeAPACpygzAB2AJpjvsAzWGBoANHABqzEK07dcBAHIoAtkIB8cAN4BYAFC64BuCgCEALjhsArkoBGwKLv2GEENmhhRLCGNAAUASk0nAwBfXTC9HVBIWDgYAWBsOWBFFUwAXicAcgAzCAgAfQBGLLgAH2y8woAmLMcdeMEk3n5BDLh3KGI2AHNyi2s7B0jGxJ4CAFkUMEZJaS5mglahUQkWdgXxlOU1OHTNOABtAGk4bsW%20BLQAXXMtkjJKMGp6BlX1CPqcyzZvYldEFBgChWFspjMmOsZBdwXQtssRBdUmpVL4EMlweYGP4sUEdAYgTBLFA2IgMdNwvVotB4C43LTyWA9oDgaDGb5tPi4FUiltzGxgAB3C4PChUWh0TrdHqiXL5YpZVH%20YROKrVPkWIUi0hi54Sqy2eyyqoFWpKlVclBsGhkaXmABEUt69rgAHpXXByFAoNAsQk4FknT1SsRMGwIPB0GhiD02CgbEhEj44v6svcdU8XnDkgjRFtkWhVOF-PVdOjeOCAHQ8rZuj015J3ZKizMSoOie0mor21RAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

That does solve the problem of getting the proper type when accessing the property but it introduces another problem because now you can add any property to this object not just `CacheWithExpiry`

e.g.,
`
const cacheMap = {
  foo1Cache: new CacheWithExpiry<string, 'foo_1'>(),
  foo2Cache: new CacheWithExpiry<number, 'foo_2'>(),
  foo3Cache: "I am not a cache"
}
`

Comment: @YSA see my edit

Comment: this should do the trick! I accepted your answer. Do you know if this is a TypeScript limitation? I feel like it makes sense to infer the property's type without having to go through the extra step of adding a function that simply returns the object but maybe I'm misunderstanding how TypeScript treats generics under the hood.

Comment: Yes, it is kind of a limitation. Right now you have to choose between defining a type or using `as const`. Otherwise the type will cancel out the `as const` statement. You will often see factory functions used to solve problems like this, because generic functions offer much more flexibility in defining generic types and only in generic functions, it is possible to infer types based on the input. In most real world cases this is ok, since you will use a function to process the object at some point anyway.